# Listing a folders / files permissions per user / group

Tags: php, com

I'm wondering if PHP has the ability to read a files / folders permissions and list them? For an example, here's a photo of the data I'm looking to retrieve.

[image]

I'm just interested in retrieving the name of the group / user as well as the permissions (such as Full Control, Modify, Read & Execute, etc.). Does anyone know if this is possible either through PHP or through COM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up building my own package for this using PHP's `exec()` and parsing the results from the windows command `icacls`.

https://github.com/stevebauman/WinPerm